# Table with custom fields

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, database-schema, entity-attribute-value

We are currently working in a CRM, and one of our tables need to have multiples field which should store custom data sent over an API, the client may need many of these fields.

Initially, we had something like the following:

```
Entity
id, -specific fields to the entity-, customField1, customField2, customField3
```

But then we were told that only 3 fields are not enough, and it was requested at least 100 fields.

So with that in mind, I hit a dilemma, should I use a EAV like structure, or just add the fields to the table (customField1, ..., customField100)?

The EAV like structure was something like:

```
Entity
id

EntityCustomField
id, entityId, fieldValue
```

The main issue here is querying, which becomes more complex (and slow?).

Some more info:

- Only strings are going to be stored in such fields.
- The fields need to be indexable and possible to search individually each one. (So encoding the data as JSON is probably not going to help here).
- The usage of non-relational databases are not possible currently.
- This table is going to have more writes than reads.
- We cannot switch RDMS.

Anyone had similar problem, and found a solution, or have experience with any of the possible solutions proposed?

Comment: I might try to separate the storage from the entity definition.  The separate table is the right way to store it, but you could add views or procedures in the database that flatten it back out for querying.

Comment: If the custom data is unique to an individual customer, and the column needs to be indexed... don't you need a customer field in your EAV?  JSON might not be out of the question entirely: http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2013/mysql-5-7-sql-functions-for-json-udf/

Comment: @thebjorn it's unique for that record, which is a lead (the application is a CRM). Thanks for the link, I will take a look.

Comment: Could you expand a little about what you mean with indexable in this context?

Comment: @thebjorn that it's possible to search for values stored in them without any data manipulation.

Comment: Do you have the option to switch the DBMS? This can be solved very efficiently with Postgres due to its indexable key/value store or the indexable JSON data type.

Comment: Then perhaps storing as json and using a full text index would be sufficient?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name unfortunately not, I would if I could. thebjorn, I've edited the question to make it more clear, the issue here is searching for the fields individually, using json with full text index is going to return invalid records if the same text is present in different fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

( I am not acquaint with doctrine2 )

Just an idea :

Why not have a table to hold field values :

```
CREATE TABLE field_values_table (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,field_value_1 varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    ,field_value_2 varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    ,field_value_3 varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    ,field_value_n varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And another table to hold corresponding field names :

```
CREATE TABLE field_names_table
(
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,field_name_1 varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    ,field_name_2 varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    ,field_name_3 varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    ,field_name_n varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And either

- consider one-to-one relation between above two tables with id as common field
- or have another table as a relation table between the above two tables

Say :

```
CREATE TABLE field_name_value_relation (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,field_names_table_row_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    ,field_values_table_row_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

So if you were to search a field named `country` having value as `New Zealand` ( you might not achieve it completely by an SQL query alone but ) a very high level SQL query could be :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    field_names_table
    LEFT OUTER JOIN field_name_value_relation
        ON field_name_value_relation.field_names_table_row_id = field_names_table.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN field_values_table
        ON field_values_table.id = field_name_value_relation.field_values_table_row_id
WHERE
        field_name_n = 'country'
    AND field_value_n = 'New Zealand'
```

It is not that simple as you would not know which all columns the `country` field name might be in the `field_names_table` .

Anyway I hope this gives some thoughts for you to accomplish your requirement .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RDBMS and dont want to switch, the only option you have for handling such usecase is by using `@JoinColumn` with `@OneToMany` mapping for persisting the entity for custom fields instead of storing directly.

If you are using any ORM reads and writes are handled efficiently and querying is also easy.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of structure that you are trying to create using the EAV can be modeled in many different ways.

My first choice would be to create a single table for each data type that you need to store, say for example 'integer', 'text' and 'datetime'.

The schema, for the 'customfields_text' table would be:

object_id, field_name, text_value

```
Primary Key = object_id + field_name
Index at text_value
```

The same schema will also apply to  'customfields_integer' and 'customfields_datetime'.

When querying, you will be able to:

```
SELECT * FROM objects o JOIN customfields_integer ci ON o.id = ci.object_id WHERE ci.field_name = 'my_custom_attribute'
```